# How to set the margin in GridLayout's first Column?

Tags: java, swing, border, layout-manager, grid-layout

I want the margin from the left side in Grid layout first column only. The Jlabel in the first column is LEFT aligned.

[image: image of the problem]

Code for the Row is

```
 lbl1 = new JLabel("Hold");
       lbl1 .setFont(new Font("Arial Black", Font.PLAIN, text));
       lbl1 .setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);
       lbl1 .setForeground(Color.decode(textColor));
       panel1.add(lbl1 );


       lbl2= new JLabel("100");
       lbl2.setFont(new Font("Arial Black", Font.PLAIN, text));
       lbl2.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
       lbl2.setForeground(Color.decode(textColor));
       panel1.add(lbl2);
```

Code for the panel is

```
setLayout(new GridLayout(0,2));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case you can set an empty border for all your "left" label.

```
lb1.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(0, 10, 0, 0));
```

This code will provide 10 points offset from the left side of the label.

Usually `GridLayout` is not a best choice for your purposes. I would advise you to look for another layout manager. The standard `GridBagLayout` is a little bit too verbouse so it would be better to learn a third-party layout like [MigLayout](http://www.miglayout.com/) or [FormLayout](http://www.jgoodies.com/freeware/libraries/forms/).